Error generating clirr-maven-plugin:2.8:clirr report: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
Getting the following error on executing mvn site command -

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.12.1:site (default-site) on project xxx: Error generating clirr-maven-plugin:2.8:clirr report: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Note that this question is similar to getting Invalid byte tag in constant pool : 19 but few points which are different in this case -

I am not using java 9 anywhere in my project. So I am not sure how tag type 19 is coming at all.
I am getting error via maven-site-plugin not tomcat
I have not defined bcel version manually in pom

output of mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.9.6
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven
Java version: 1.8.0_402-internal, vendor: OpenLogic-OpenJDK, runtime: /Users/xxx/Downloads/openlogic-openjdk-8u402-b06-mac-x64/jdk1.8.0_402.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "14.3.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
I am expecting the command to get executed successfully without any error.

Which Maven version, JDK version, and other plugin versions do you use? Also the given plugin clirr-maven-plugin is of 2016... really old... also the maven-site-plugin is more or less up-to-date... I recommend to remove the clirr-maven-plugin because it's Maven 2 based... use other things ...

@khmarbaise updated the questionwith output of mvn version command, maven-site-plugin version is 3.12.1 and clirr-maven-plugin version is 2.8 as mentioned in the error message

As per https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/changes-report.html, Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19 issue was resolved in release 6.2,
I used mvn dependency:resolve-plugins to check which version of bcel is pulled by clirr, I found out that -
org.codehaus.mojo:clirr-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:2.8:runtime was pulling org.apache.bcel:bcel:jar:6.0 hence I force updated the plugin to use 6.2 which helped me to resolve the issue using -
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>clirr-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${clirr.plugin.version}</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.bcel</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
        <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

